# How to turn off exception handling?

Tags: c++, performance, exception

In the book More Effective C++ (Number 15), I read that code becomes significantly slower if exceptions are enabled, even if they are not used. In my opinion, exceptions are of limited use, and I try to avoid them, but this is another topic.

I do not entirely understand his statement:

1. What does enabling/disabling exceptions mean? It it the difference between having zero or more than zero try/catch blocks? Is it a compiler flag? What happens if I use a DLL in which exceptions can occur?
2. Suppose no exception is ever thrown:

   - Does the code become slower as a whole or are only the parts where the program enters/exits try/catch blocks become slower? According to the author, both is true.
3. How can I compile without exceptions? Can I do this even if I have try/catch blocks? Can I do this if DLLs I use might throw exceptions?

Comment: The book is old, compilers have become a heckofalot smarter since then.  A decent one today can do it with zero overhead, using table-based lookup from the instruction address to find code that needs to run when the stack is unwound.  But if you want to fret about it anyway then look through the compiler options, most have an option to disable the feature.

Comment: " In my opinion, exceptions are of limited use, and I try to avoid them, but this is another topic." My guess is that your code does not call any fallible system call. Are you programming a CPU heater?

Comment: @user4590120: Exceptions are not the only way to deal with failure. I use return codes to check for success or failure.

Answer (score 6):

> What does enabling/disabling exceptions mean?

Passing a flag to the compiler which disables standard conformance in relation to exceptions and makes it not generate any exception support.

> What happens if I use a DLL in which exceptions can occur?

If some library handles exception internally, nothing. If it lets it escape to the caller (I never saw any library which does that, because of ABI issues, but whatever), your program crashes (in best case) as it cannot handle it. If there is a wrapper for DLL which your code include and which converts error codes to exceptions (common occurence), then it is the same as if you used exceptions in your code.

> Does the code become slower as a whole or are only the parts where the program enters/exits try/catch blocks become slower? According to the author, both is true.

Notice that the book you are citing is old. Compilers are evolving. Modern compilers use zero-cost exceptions which do not incure perfomance cost if exception is not thrown. Exception handling does make executable larger as it should generate all data and code needed to process exceptions, but it should not make it slower on non-exceptional path.

> How can I compile without exceptions? Can I do this even if I have try/catch blocks?

You do that in compiler-specific way. Consult your compiler documentation. Usually doing so makes compiler reject code containing any exception-related facilities, e.g. point out `try` as unrecognised identifier.

Comment: "Exception handling does make executable larger" - larger than what? the equivalent program with error return values also needs code and data to deal with those. The big advantage of exceptions is that the error handling code and data can be left on disk initially, so your program starts faster.

Comment: "it should not make it slower on non-exceptional path" - in fact, modern exception handling makes the non-error path _faster_. This is because the compiler can identify and optimize that path. With error return values, the compiler doesn't know whether to optimize the `==0` or `!=0` return value, as different functions use different return value conventions.

Comment: @MSalters than the exact same code compiled without exception support (this means original code have to be without exception handling at all). This gets rid of exception handling for standard library (`new` usually turns into nothrow `new`, replacing `bad_alloc` exception with null pointer access crash later, for example)

Comment: Well, removing functionality (error handling or otherwise) usually makes programs smaller. That's not a meaningful observation.

Comment: my dlls throw errors since a very long time and the calling program catches them without crashing but printing out the message returned via what().